# Deleting iCloud photo duplicates

Tags: icloud, photos

After downloading my phone to a MacBook Pro I have experienced multiple photo duplicates in iCloud. 30,000 plus photos are now on my iCloud and the duplicate photo fixer only scans 2200. Any advice?

Answer (score -1):

I have Photo Fixer Pro and guessing the lite version you have may have a limit.  My icloud photos have over 80,570 photos and videos and if I scan weeks to months it scans way over 30,000

my first try it crashed because I have so many but it scanned 53,204 the first time until I narrow my search down.